# Using WP7 Date & Time Converters in the code behind file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, toolkit

currently I have this in my XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <toolkit:RelativeTimeConverter x:Key="RelativeTimeConverter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

....

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtTimeAdded" Text="{Binding DateAndTime, Converter={StaticResource RelativeTimeConverter}}" />
```

But I don't want to bind it to the textbox, instead I want to use it in the code behind file.
Any ideas how to do that?

Based on this: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/08/august2011phonetoolkit/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var converter = new RelativeTimeConverter();
var relativeTime = (string)converter.Convert(e.Result.DateTime,null,null,new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

txtTimeAdded.Text = relativeTime;
```

(If you're using the other fields, you should pass them properly. But from your Binding, it doesn't appear that you are.)

Comment: ok, so I tried this:
    var converter = new RelativeTimeConverter();
    converter.Convert(e.Result.DateTime.ToLocalTime(), null, null, null);

But I get an NullReferenceException error on the 2nd line.

Comment: Ok, so I solved the null refrence, but now i have this:

    var converter = new RelativeTimeConverter();
    converter.Convert(e.Result.DateTime.ToLocalTime(), null, null, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
    txtTimeAdded.Text = converter.ToString();

But now the txt returns this:
"Microsoft.Phone.Controls.RelativeTimeConverter"